# References for relative/scaled time?

Tags: preprocessing, time

I have time-based (e.g., patient) data where some subjects (patients) were treated for a longer time than others. I want to analyze the treatment effects where observations are really noisy (so looking at individual subject's trajectory is not very informative). I do not have enough subjects to segment them &c.

More precisely, the data is $(t_{ip},o_{ip})$ for events $i$ and patients $p$ and some patients have more observations than others and, more ominously, the time range for each patient can be very different (e.g., days vs weeks) so if I look at the *correlation* of observations with time, the patients with longer treatment period will completely dominate the picture.

The obvious way to eliminate this disparity is to scale time for each patient so that every patient starts treatment at time 0 and ends it at time 1, as with [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) (which is, apparently, so standard that there are no references in the page).

Are there any published references for this methodology?
Or maybe just people who use it?

PS. I am ***NOT*** asking what to do with the data (although I am open to suggestions, of course). I am asking for published works using the `MinMaxScaler` methodology I described.

Answer (score 0):

> and, more ominously, the time range for each patient can be very different

This is a bit vague.
It is consistent with my current understanding
of the problem: "Some patient observation histories extend for ten hours,
and some for five orders of magnitude greater than that, about a decade."

The relevant timescale for progression of various diseases,
and for various therapeutic interventions,
may fall somewhere along that continuum.
There are certain remission events that simply cannot occur in less than a day.
To scale all patient histories to the unit interval,
without spelling out the various assumptions and constraints,
seems too simplistic.

Consider segmenting the patient population into similar timespan histories.
Minimally, if you're interested in efficacy of an intervention,
the segment being examined should cover enough calendar time
that the intervention could possibly have had some effect.

Comment: you are too focused on the medical domain. this is ***NOT*** my question.

Comment: There is a Generative Process in the world, which produces observables. We wish to analyze these observables across "short" and "long" timescales. In the record we do not currently see any explicit axioms  or assumptions about invariance of observable effects w.r.t. timescale. As stated the OP admits of very large variation across patients. It would be helpful to narrow the scope to a more tractable problem. There is for example a robust literature on Preventive Maintenance, where measuring rust effects over the course of months may indicate one intervention or another, but machine != patient.